# How to disable password checking in django-allauth

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-allauth

I had a problem to disable password checking (password1 with password2) in `django-allauth` package. Because nowadays, sign-up forms never get two passwords in form.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After searching, I found this switch to turn this option off:

```
ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_PASSWORD_VERIFICATION = False
```

You can put this on your `settings.py` file.

This switch is `True` by default, you can set this to`False`, then `django-allauth` never check passwords in sign-up form and `password2` became optional.

Comment: Since 0.26, this settings was change to ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_EMAIL_ENTER_TWICE = False

Comment: There is actually a ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_PASSWORD_ENTER_TWICE setting now

Answer (score 0):

By default while signing up for a account in `django-all-auth`, a user has to type in his password twice. This is done to prevent unintentional typing errors.

This feature is configurable and can be changed via the `ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_PASSWORD_VERIFICATION` setting (which OP also mentioned above).

As per [`django-all-auth`](http://django-allauth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/configuration.html) docs:

> ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_PASSWORD_VERIFICATION (=True)
>   When signing up, let the user type in their password twice to avoid typo’s.

`ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_PASSWORD_VERIFICATION` is set to `True` by default. Since you don't want this functionality you can just set this setting to `False` in your `settings.py` file.